# Quartz/Tomcat two contexts being initialized

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, tomcat9, server.xml

I have a java webapp and front end running on Tomcat 9 on a VPS. The webapps folder has the war file and the front end code (index.html, etc) is placed in `webapps/root/app`. Within the java webapp is a class that extends `QuartzInitializerListener` annotated with `@WebListener` for defining triggers and scheduling jobs. No other listeners have been explicitly specified in web.xml or otherwise for quartz.

The issue I am facing is that two contexts (and hence, two schedulers) are being initialized, causing two jobs to be fired instead of one. Perhaps having two Hosts with the same appBase is the issue? If so, how can I prevent this behaviour while having the localhost for tomcat manager (for deploying, starting, stopping, etc) and another host exclusively for the webapp and front end?

I have tried:

- removing the first host, and setting the name of the second host to localhost -> This works, except I can access the tomcat manager through `http://foo.bar.com/manager/html` which is not desired. I would like to access tomcat only using the IP address and not the domain name.
- moving the webapp+frontend only and placing it into a separate folder in the tomcat directory (changed the second `Host` appBase to `foobarapp`) -> I cannot deploy to `foobarapp` as it does not have a tomcat manager associated with it.

A workaround currently implemented is to stop the second context initialization by using a file lock. This works as intended, as the first context that gets access on the file locks it and writes `true` to show that the context has been initialized. The second context stops execution after seeing that `true` is set in the file. On stopping, the first context sets the value in the file as `false`.

**server.xml**

```
<Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="false">
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
</Host>


<Host name="foo.bar.com" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <Alias>foo.bar.com</Alias>

    <Context path="" docBase="{tomcat_directory}/webapps/ROOT/app" debug="0" privileged="true" />

    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" prefix="foo_bar." suffix=".txt" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" resolveHosts="false" />
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />
</Host>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please paste the contents of  your quartz.properties.Are you running the quartz in cluster mode.Are both scheduler instances sharing same database?

Comment: I am not using any quartz.properties (I did use it to test out XML based configuration, but I have not used it since moving to XML-less config). It is not running in cluster mode (I am using the default quartz config). The Jobs themselves use Hibernate to connect to the database, but no job store is specified for the scheduler if that's what you mean.